# modules needed to create a custom widget with ipython?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

what are modules needed to create a custom widget? I have installed ipywidgets module with the command : "conda install ipywidgets" and I tried to run this example found in github [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipywidgets/blob/52d1ff2090801856d4863c8768488a43e7266295/examples/Custom%20Widget%20-%20Hello%20World.ipynb) but the browser says that the file "jupyter-js-widgets" is not found.

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What conda version are you using? Did you try installing it in the non-root environment?

You can try doing:

1. `conda create -n test-ipywidgets python=3.5`
2. `source activate test-ipywidgets`
3. `conda install ipywidgets`
4. `jupyter notebook`

Then navigate to the Hello World notebook file that you have downloaded.